# Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code

Tags: apache, python-3.x

when i restart my apache2 i got this error's message

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

i insert this code to /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
<Directory /var/www/test>
        Options +ExecCGI
        DirectoryIndex index.py
</Directory>
AddHandler cgi-script .py

...

DocumentRoot /var/www/test

...
```

when i erase the code, my apache can restart normally, but i need this code to run cgi on my ubuntu 16.04

i follow this link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-apache-mysql-and-python-lamp-server-without-frameworks-on-ubuntu-14-04

please help.

Answer (score 3):

The solution for

```
apache2.service Failed Because the Control Process Exited with Error Code
```

is

```
$ cd /etc/apache2/
$ sudo nano apache2.conf
```

then find

```
"Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf"
```

Remove the above line and save it, then run

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

You will do after doing this.

Answer (score 1):

if you use

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

to install Apache2

you can try it！

```
 sudo a2enmod proxy proxy_ajp proxy_balancer proxy_connect proxy_ftp proxy_http
```

Comment: use "apt-get install " to install Apache2 ，not exist  proxy module

Comment: How does this solve the problem? According to the OP, Apache was already installed and working basically

Answer (score 0):

It can be a syntax mistake in /opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
delete it and all will start working
If you use XAMPP

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was caused by enabling many php versions in appache2 config .

I have 3 php versions on my env, I fix the error by by disable all php versions and after I anabled one version .

Solution :

stop appache2 :

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
```

Disable all php vsions  :

```
sudo a2dismod phpV.1
```

...

```
sudo a2dismod phpV.n
```

select php version to enable :

```
sudo update-alternatives --config php
```

Enable one php vsions  :

```
sudo a2enmod phpV.x
```

Start appache 2 server :

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

Answer (score 0):

reinstall Apache2 HTTP Server
this fixed my problem